# how can i make my css file available for my entire application in Gwt?

Tags: css, gwt, gwt-platform

I'm using GWTP and Maven, i have a .css file which specifies different styles for the widgets in my application, and my application has some sub modules also so my question is how can i make my css available for the whole application ?
how can i make my css file available for sub modules also?

Comment: are you using ClientBundle or how are you referencing your css file?

Comment: i'm using <ui:style src="abc.css">in my ui.xml file and <stylesheet src='abc.css'/> in my module xml file. i don't have good idea about using ClientBundle for css but i will use it if it simplify the issue thanks,

Comment: sub-modules are referring to maven sub-modules or different views in the same GWTP application?

Comment: maven sub-modules and each sub module will contain different views for all these views i should use one .css file and i should able to make it  available to every view

Comment: hmm there must be a maven way to do it. 
But you can try to package your css files as a jar package and make the modules depend on it. Haven't tried it myself tough.

Answer (score 0):

To benefit from GWT's CssResource advantages (like you do when you say `<ui:style src="abc.css"/>`) you'll have to use a ClientBundle.

ClientBundles are basically Java classes that represent CSS and other resources.  Without GWT, you'd put your CSS and images directly into your HTML code.  With GWT, you want to do everything through Java... and that means using Java design patterns.

As you know, you can't just use a global variable in Java programs, and the same is true for css with GWT.  You'll have to pass your CSS classes to your libraries as Java objects.  You can use static references in many places, but I prefer to actually pass in CSS objects to maximize flexibility later, and I think that's an established best practice.

TL;DR:

Figure out ClientBundles and do as you'd normally do to pass Java variables between libraries.

Comment: do you have any idea about how the gwt default themes(Standard/Dark) are working just by inheriting them in module file, and these are defined in gwt-user.jar as modules. if i could do something similar to that then it may work